# How to Skip Checkstyle Analysis for few lines of code in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

As part of SonarQube checkstyle analysis, we need to skip few lines of code from being analysed.

In the java code, we are using this format:

```
    //CHECKSTYLE:OFF
....
....
    //CHECKSTYLE:ON
```

So, I tried giving this in SonarQube, under Settings --> Java --> Checkstyle, but its not giving the desired results

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter">
        <property name="offCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE:OFF"/>
        <property name="onCommentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE:ON"/>
</module>
```

I could explicitly exclude that file from being picked up for analysis by declaring sonar.exclusions in the pom file like this

```
<properties>
                <sonar.exclusions>src/main/java/<file-name>.java</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
```

But I'm not sure why this configuration is not being picked up for analysis. Is there something that I miss here ?

**EDIT**:

I found out that it is for only SQUID rules, which are activated in place of few deprecated checkstyle rules, that are not being skipped with CHECKSTYLE OFF & ON comments.

So, is there a way to skip SQUID rules apart from @Suppresswarnings("squid:S00016") annotations? I'm looking for something like CHECKSTYLE OFF, ON used for checkstyle.

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: Did you try another value? BEGIN GENERATED CODE/END GENERATED CODE for example?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well from this page
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionCommentFilter

But results are same.

Comment: Checkstyle developer here. @Ron4326, this seems to be a bug in Sonar Checkstyle integration. Could you please submit a ticket to https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle? Thanks